# How to exclude a class from 'exception throw' processing

Tags: exception, appcode

I am working with cocos2d, in particular the cocos Dhension audio engine. It turns out that it is quite noisy (throwing exceptions), and i would like to exclude it when turning on 'exceptions throws'. Is there a way to exclude a specific class ?

Comment: Did you ask this also on AppCode forum/support?

Comment: not yet ... errr ... ive been quite noisy on there lately, trying to lie low fow a while ! but i will. I'll let you know. Btw, giant leap with the latest EAP build , solves quite a few issues for me.

Comment: I'm very interested in the correction of slow index on change target/device as I told you as 'giampaolo' on the AppCode forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/440501;jsessionid=6257F6CC99F3C4E0C693521C724B3179?tstart=0

Comment: right now its looking very good for me ... change target in 2 seconds ... but my app aint your app ! who knows :). The editor is screaming fast compared to 1.6.n and first EAP that came out.

Comment: do you think that my answer is the right one? Did u investigated more on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can't. AppCode cannot do more that lldb (or gdb) does. I checked lldb documentation and I didn't found what you are looking for. So, neither AppCode can.

Comment: have not found how to exclude the noisy class, but at least (EAP 2.0), i can disable exception processing until a specific breakpoint is hit.